# Oracle Index Sort Order and Joining

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables that are a few millions of rows with indexes. I'm looking to convert one of the indexes to DESC order to optimize some operations. However, will that affect joinining speed or other optimizations?

For example:

`Table A:

a_id (pk)`

Table B:
b_id (pk)
a_id (fk)

If A.a_id is stored as DESC and B.a_id is stored ASC will I encounter any problems or slowness on joins? Will oracle be able to use the indexes for joining even though they have different sort orders? Do I have to make B.a_id DESC as well or create a second index that is DESC ? Obviously I'd like to try a simple experiment but I don't have DBA access or a spare oracle setup to work with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will oracle be able to use the indexes
>   for joining even though they have
>   different sort orders?

Indexes are not used "for joining".  They're used to access data.  The row sources thus created are then joined.  The only reason I can think of that the sort order of the index would have any impact on joining would be if a merge join is occurring and the index is being used to avoid sorting.  In this case, the impact of changing to a descending index might be that the data needs to be sorted in memory after it is accessed; or it might not, if the optimizer is intelligent enough to simply walk through that data in reverse order when doing the merge.

If you have queries whose execution plans rely on using the index on A.A_ID to get the data in ascending order (either for purposes of a merge join or to meet your requested ordering of the results), then changing the index to descending order could have an impact.

**Edit:**  Just did a quick test on some sample data.  The optimizer does seem to have the capability to merge row sources sorting in opposite orders without resorting either of them.  So at the most obvious level, having one index ascending and the other descending should not cause serious performance problems.  However, it does look like the descending indexes can have other effects on the execution plan -- in my case, the ascending index was used for a fast full scan, while the descending one was used for a range scan.  This could cause changes in query performance -- good or bad -- but the only way to know for certain is to test it.

Comment: Thanks Dave! You accurately corrected my faulty assumption in your first 3 sentences.

Answer (score 2):

Oracle implements indexes as doubly-linked lists, so it makes no difference whether you specify an ASC or DESC index for a single column.

DESC indexes are a special case that helps when you have a multi-column index, e.g. if I have a query that often orders by colA ASC, colB DESC, then I might decide to add an index on (colA, colB DESC) in order to avoid a sort.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get what you're trying to ask - you cannot "store" in descending or ascending order. You can fetch the results of the query and order it using `ORDER BY` clause which will sort the resulting set in ascending or descending order.

There is no guarantee that you're inserting any data in ascending or descending order.

Consequently, the "order" by which it is inserted will have no bearing on the performance because there is no order

Comment: Never heard of descending indexes? create index idx_emp_ename on emp(ename DESC). -1 for saying you can't do something Oracle lets you do.

Comment: @bot403 honestly, I hadn't. Looking up documentation now.

Comment: Sathya is dead on correct.  The only way to get an order out of Oracle, is to use the ORDER keyword.   You can not infer the order based on what is in the index, ascending or descending, or omitted.

Comment: I'm not looking to return data in any specific order, just wondering how the different index type influence optimizer decisions and if the optimizer can use 2 indexes which are sorted differently.

Comment: To expand - I don't care how they're stored on disk, and only sometimes so I care about the order they're returned only how fast I can get the data. I don't want to sacrifice an unordered JOIN speed for faster ORDER'd queries. Can different index types be used for both types of queries?

Answer (score 0):

Developing without a development and test system?
Your answer is to develop with one.  Oracle comes on all platforms, just install, add data, do your work.

For you, just live dangerously and do the index change, who cares what happens. Grab for that brass ring. So you miss. You won't lose any data.

Comment: I am on a dev DB but I dont have DDL modification powers to that one either :(

Comment: So you were asked to run DDL changes but do not have the privileges to do so?

Comment: No, I have the ability to ask for DDL changes if it will help my queries.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking an index can do scanning in asc/desc order since the 2 pointers in the index structure are sufficient to identify leaf blocks and corresponding blocks while doing scan based on asc/desc order without sorting in the memory.

However if we create an index with desc column definition its structure will be much larger than the a normal index since the normal index has a 90-10 splits (incrementing row ids) where as desc index  will be 50-50 splits and will lead to unused space and a candidate for rebuild which will require additional maintenance and overhead.

DESC indexes can be helpful when you have a multi-column index where one column is need in asc while the other in desc to avoid sorting in the memory.

Answer (score -1):

Early optimization is a waste of time. Just leave this problem and do the next thing.  When there are 100 million rows in this table change the indexes and test what happens, until then your ten rows of data are not worth the time to "optimize".

Comment: Who said I have 10 rows now? I already have millions of rows and need to optimize. I'm trying to determine the impact of index order on different types of queries.